# Text centred and middle over image

Tags: css, magento, magento2

I'm trying to redesign a category page on magento to display the category image full width with a max height and have the category title displayed in the same box centred on the image.

I've managed to move the category image and title into the page wrapper with the below code

```
<move element="category.image" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content" />
<move element="page.main.title" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content"/>
```

The HTML

```
<div class="amryw-container">
  <!-- Lorem Ipsum -->
  <div class="page-title-wrapper">
    <h1 class="page-title" id="page-title-heading" aria-labelledby="page-title-heading&#x20;toolbar-amount">
      <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper">Classic Wax Melts</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="category-image"><img src="https://and-it.co.uk/test-store/pub/media/catalog/category/amryw-classic-wax-melts-banner.jpg" alt="Classic&#x20;Wax&#x20;Melts" title="Classic&#x20;Wax&#x20;Melts" class="image" /></div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.amryw-container {
    display: contents;
}
.category-image {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    align-self: center;
    display: contents;
}
.category-image .image {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 340px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

But can't figure out how to get the category title to be in the centre of the image.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Page I'm trying to edit: https://and-it.co.uk/test-store/classic-wax-melts

Page I'm trying to replicate: https://amryw.co.uk/classic-wax-melts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of another user so posting it for others to use.

Achieved by removing the two basic blocks category.image and page.main.title and creating a custom block.

catalog_category_view.xml

create your PHTML inside your theme \ module : (Note, if you have a custom theme inherited from Luma you can just place it inside: Magento_Catalog\templates\category\view\custom_category_title.phtml,

```
<referenceContainer name="category.view.container">

    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="custom.category.top.view" template="category/view/custom_category_title.phtml"/>

</referenceContainer>
<referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
```

instead if you have only a custom module you'll have to place the Layout.xml [catalog_category_view] and the template [custom_category_title] inside your module: Vendor_Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml and Vendor_Module\view\frontend\templates\category\view\custom_category_title.phtml)

\category\view\custom_category_title.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
 */
    $_currentCat = $block->getCurrentCategory();
    $categoryTitle = $_currentCat->getName();
    $categoryImage = $_currentCat->getImageUrl();

?>

<div>
   <div class="category-image-custom">
       <img title="<?=$categoryTitle?>" alt="<?=$categoryTitle?>" src="<?=$categoryImage?>">
       <h1><?=$categoryTitle?></h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

And finally, the CSS

```
.category-image-custom img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top;
    margin: auto;
    height: 300px;
}

.category-image-custom h1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 40%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font: 400 50px/1.2 Poiret One, Helvetica Neue, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

.category-image-custom {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else looking to do the same!

Answer (score 1):

If the title is a text element, assign `text-align:center;` to its parent. If the title isn't a text element, you can force an element to behave this way by assigning it `display:inline-block;`

This is assuming you're using a background-image (which you should)

This might be an easier solution for you: https://jsfiddle.net/8reLz1gk/1/

For more info check out W3: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_text_center2

Comment: I've looked at the page you're linking too before and tried applying it to my situation. But I can't get it working. I thought originally it might be because the two elements weren't in the same container, so I fixed that and still; can't get it to work.

Comment: Alternatively you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8reLz1gk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can set that image as background-image for your div. And then simply display the text in the middle of it.

index.html:

```
<div class="container">
   <p>TEXT HERE</p>
</div>
```

style.css:

```
.container {
  background-image: url("./img.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container p {
  color: rgb(65, 150, 107);
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

like this:

[image]

Comment: I did think about this. The problem I have is each category would have a different background image

Comment: Background image is definitely the way to go here. If you have a different background image for each category, you could always use some simple javascript to change the image when the category is active.

Comment: I posted a new answer. It was a nice challenge ;D

Comment: Javascript is unfortunately not something I'm overly familiar with (or at all for that matter). And I wouldn't know where to start implementing it in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

## NEW ANSWER:

Well in my html, I put a div around my img, so I could give it a `overflow: hidden;`. I gave the 'img' and the container around it `height :100%`. With the `overflow: hidden;` the image stays within the container. Now I have an image, exactly the same size as my container.\

Now the for the 'p'. It took me some time to come up with this idea:
I first gave my 'p' `height: 100%;` so it has the same height as the div containing the img and the p tag. 
Now I use `transform: translateY(-100%);`, which is moving up the p tag. Now the p tag and the img are in the same place, occupying the same space (both have same height).
And for centering my 'p', I simply use flex attributes.

index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="./img.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

style.css:

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.container p {
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: That didn't quite work either. I've updated my question to include all the HTML and CSS I have at the moment for that particular element. Starting tot think it might not be possible due to some other reason.

Comment: If you want to follow my second answer on your file, you have to change the place of your text and your image, otherwise when you use `transform: xx` the image comes on top of the text. And you cant simply use `z-index` there, because of the stacking context. Simply change their places. And write simpler, lots of your css lines aren't necessary.